# How to join on binary field?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

In Scala/Spark, I am trying to do the following:

```
val portCalls_Ports = 
  portCalls.join(ports, portCalls("port_id") === ports("id"), "inner")
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
     binary type expression port_id cannot be used in join conditions;
```

It's true that this is a binary type:

```
root
 |-- id: binary (nullable = false)
 |-- port_id: binary (nullable = false)
     .
     .
     .

+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  id|             port_id|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[FB 89 A0 FF AA 0...|[B2 B2 84 B9 52 2...|
```

as is `ports("id")`.

I am using the following libraries:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // Spark dependencies
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.6.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.6.2",
  // Third-party libraries
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
  "net.sf.jopt-simple" % "jopt-simple" % "5.0.3"
)
```

Note that I am using JDBC to read database tables.

What is the best way to fix this problem?

Comment: Binary type expressions can be used in join conditions in Spark 2.1.0, but not in versions before it.

Comment: I removed the jdbc tag, because this problem seems to be purely inside spark, and is not related to using jdbc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pre **Spark 2.1.0**, the best workaround I know of is using the `base64` function to convert the binary columns into Strings, and compare these:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val portCalls_Ports =
  portCalls.join(ports, base64(portCalls("port_id")) === base64(ports("id")), "inner")
```

Comment: Sorry - edited the post to include the import; I recommend making a habit of adding this import to every DataFrame-related piece of code ;)